# Calculating revenue in excel

Tags: excel, revenue

Can't calculate the Revenue since the Cell Price contains the 'BDT'.[image: Revenue Chart]

Comment: I assume your question is "I have a cell with mixed numeric and text data. I need to multiply the numeric data by another number. Is there a formula that will let me extract the numeric data so I can use it in another formula?"  Am I right?

Comment: Exactly I was trying to mean that.

Answer (score 2):

I find using `SUBSTITUTE()` to be a pretty clean solution for this.  `SUBSTITUTE()` does a simple find and replace of text in a cell, where applicable.  Then `VALUE()` ensures that the new text is treated as a numeric value rather than a text string.

For example:

```
=B2*VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"BDT ",""))
```

This saves you from having to calculate `LENGTH()` or spaces in the text with `FIND()`, etc., so I think it's a little easier to read and implement than other solutions.  And it'll work even if "BDT " doesn't appear in the cell, i.e., if there's nothing to replace, then it just... won't replace.

@GPHOfficial's solution will work too, but I find that little less simple to read.

Finally, the "most correct" solution is probably to create a custom currency symbol/format, so you can apply the format in a way that formulas will completely neglect the symbol and only recognize the value.

Comment: Have to upvote this, but would like to say that doing substitute(...) *1 is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the formula [=RIGHT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/right-rightb-functions-240267ee-9afa-4639-a02b-f19e1786cf2f)

I implemented the formula here, the formula should be interchangeable between Excel and Google Sheets

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT($A7,LEN($A7)-FIND(" ",$A7))*$B7,"")
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PDqQj1y1G56FKzz0Lp86aM-fzso2-IMTZCvZpOoS3go/edit?usp=sharing

(This is based on the assumption that there is a space between the Price and the Currency Code)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the BDT.

Use Text to Columns, Delimited, Next, Space, Next, Do not import column (skip), Finish to remove the BDT and leave the prices as true numbers. If you must show the BDT prefix, use a custom number format of `\B\D\T General`.

[image]